# sun.misc.BASE64Decoder is it thread-safe?

Tags: java, thread-safety, decoder

I'm going to use `sun.misc.BASE64Decoder` 's  `decodeBuffer(String inputString)` in my code. Multiple threads will be calling this function on the same decoder object.

Is this thread safe ?

Thanks and regards,
Raj

Comment: Uhm, it is generally a bad idea to rely on anything sun.*. Why don't you use Guava? It has BASE64 encoding classes, and as everything Guava, it is fast and works very reliably

Comment: Better than that, immutable. [link to javadoc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v16.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/io/BaseEncoding.html)

Comment: Note that Java SE 8 introduced a Base64 decoder: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Decoder.html

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(String lexicalXSDBase64Binary)`instead. It's standard Java API, besides it is thread-safe